# Plone setting up static images directory

Tags: plone

Plone 4.3 is installed at c:\Plone43 directory with the site.zcml located in c:\Plone43\parts\instance\etc\site.zcml

All I want to do is setup a directory where I can put some images or resources and be able to access them using a URL like http://wiki.mycompany.net:8080/++resources++PROJECTNAME/images/someimage.png

I have activated the plone.resource 1.0.2 but have no idea where to put any images now or how to configure it. I have heard people talking about zcml but I have no idea what zcml file they are talking about.

I added the  line in the site.zcml and then the plone site would not come up so I had to remove it.

Can someone please help me configure a static resource folder please? I am ok to configure a global one directly in the site.zcml if its possible.

Current site.zcml looks like this:

```
<configure
xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
xmlns:meta="http://namespaces.zope.org/meta"
xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five">

<include package="Products.Five" />
<meta:redefinePermission from="zope2.Public" to="zope.Public" />


<!-- Load the meta -->
<include files="package-includes/*-meta.zcml" />
<five:loadProducts file="meta.zcml"/>

<!-- Load the configuration -->
<include files="package-includes/*-configure.zcml" />
<five:loadProducts />

<!-- Load the configuration overrides-->
<includeOverrides files="package-includes/*-overrides.zcml" />
<five:loadProductsOverrides />


<securityPolicy
  component="AccessControl.security.SecurityPolicy" />


</configure>
```

Comment: There is an idiomatic assumption Plone people make: any customizations or integrations you do are done in add-on packages.  My answer below should provide some direction toward creating an add-on for the sole purpose of including static resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about site.zcml; just create an small [add-on package](https://developer.plone.org/getstarted/index.html) that has (1) a directory for your static resources, (2) a configure.zcml file using a [browser:resourceDirectory](https://developer.plone.org/templates_css_and_javascripts/resourcefolders.html) declaration.  Put your add-on in source control somewhere.

Your package should set up the following structure (assumes UNIX, you can easily translate this to Windows equivalents as you see fit, rename package appropriately):

```
~/my-buildout $ cd src
~/my-buildout/src $ mkdir -p myorg.packagename/myorg/packagename/static
~/my-buildout/src $ cd myorg.packagename
~/my-buildout/src/myorg.packagename $ vim setup.py  # edit as needed
...  # see http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html
~/my-buildout/src/myorg.packagename $ vim myorg/__init__.py
```

Make your namespace package work (in myorg/__init__.py):

```
try:
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
    from pkgutil import extend_path
    __path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Other boilerplate:

```
~/my-buildout/src/myorg.packagename $ echo "#" > myorg/packagename/__init__.py
~/my-buildout/src/myorg.packagename $ vim myorg/packagename/configure.zcml
```

Your configure.zcml should look like:

```
<configure
  xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
  xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser">

  <browser:resourceDirectory
    name="MYPROJECTNAME"
    directory="static"
    />

</configure>
```

Installing add-ons is well-documented for Plone, so I am omitting description of that.